# How to join two different database table and fetch values. db1 and db2

Tags: hibernate, inner-join, hibernate-mapping

Am trying to create a page , were i am going to show all values from table1 of db1, i need to join one more table db2.table2
         using this property :

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`

and

```
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER , targetEntity =BranchDAO.class )
        @JoinColumn(name = "BranchId")
        private BranchDAO branch;


   **  SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT `id`, `Name`, `Address`, `ContactNumber`, `EmailID`, b.branch_name " +
                " FROM vrfdb.lessee_master l " +
                " INNER JOIN leavemanagement.branchmaster b ON l.BranchId =  b.branch_id ");**
```

Answer (score 0):

answer for the above problem is , we need to create VIEW in mysql.
Create view branch_master as SELECT * FROM ldb.branch_master.

Thats it ,,